# Why do we get a StackOverflowError for discovering @Inject methods?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, stack-overflow, guice

We're hitting a StackOverflowError's because in Guice we have deep nested injections.

Looking in the callstack, there's a pattern of Guice analyzing a class Constructor, then discovering a new class that was injected, and the repeating this process until its 16 classes deep and POP.

I imagine that there's a way for me to instruct Guice before hand about a bunch of classes that will need to be injected. I'm not sure what that process would be.

```
com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: 
com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: 
..... x16
com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: 
com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: 
java.lang.StackOverflowError


at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(SourceFile:2199)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(SourceFile:3934)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(SourceFile:3938)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(SourceFile:4821)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(SourceFile:4827)
at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(SourceFile:48)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get(SourceFile:50)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize(SourceFile:136)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding(SourceFile:547)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(SourceFile:884)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(SourceFile:805)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(SourceFile:282)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(SourceFile:214)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalFactory(SourceFile:890)
at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.notify(SourceFile:46)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProcessedBindingData.runCreationListeners(SourceFile:50)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(SourceFile:134)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(SourceFile:107)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(SourceFile:96)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(SourceFile:73)


Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(SourceFile:2199)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(SourceFile:3934)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(SourceFile:3938)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(SourceFile:4821)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(SourceFile:4827)
at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(SourceFile:48)
at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.get(SourceFile:68)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.createConstructor(SourceFile:74)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.access$000(SourceFile:29)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(SourceFile:37)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(SourceFile:33)
at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.load(SourceFile:37)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(SourceFile:3524)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(SourceFile:2317)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(SourceFile:2280)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(SourceFile:2195)
... 35 more
```

and so on for x16 recusions until you get a StackOverflowError

Comment: This sounds complicated enough that we really need a [mcve] to be able to help out. Can you [edit] your post with a reproducible example?

Answer (score 1):

Addding the bind(Class clazz) to modules configure() method did the trick.

Instead of it resolving the relationships recursively, it already knew about most of them and the stack never went over 2 or three layers deep.